# typescript resolving not actually optional optional property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript to bear with me here if this is not how things are supposed to work.

I have a couple of goals in converting this js to ts.

```
Item = {}

Item.buy = function (id) {}
Item.sell = function (id) {}
```

I'm trying to get intellisense to autocomplete on `Item.` either buy or sell. I would also want to use dot notation to create these methods in arbitrary files without putting everything in the initial bracket. So I have something like this:

```
interface Item {}
const Item: Item = {};

interface Item {
  buy?: Function
}
Item.buy = function () {
  Item.render()
  return "bought"
}

interface Item {
  sell?: Function
}
Item.sell = function () {
  Item.render()
  return "sold"
}

interface Item {
  render?: Function
}
Item.render = function () {
    return 1
}
```

The problem here now is that render is an optional property and hence I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

How can I make ts not check for this error? Since Item is not a class there's only ever going to be 1 item and it'll definitely have the render method, there is not ever going to be an instance where that error checking is useful. Or to put it another way, it's not actually optional, I only set it to be optional to work around `const Item: Item = {};` erroring if I don't have it be optional.

Is there a way to let ts know that or use a different pattern in the first place?

Comment: "*I only set it to be optional to work around const Item: Item = {}; erroring*" then just set it to mandatory and don't trigger the error? `item: Item = { render: /* whatever */ }`

Comment: You can't do that. "I would also want to use dot notation to create these methods...without putting everything in the initial bracket" your options are to either 1) put everything in the initial definition. 2) give up on type safety 3) compose objects that are fully defined at the first assignment a la #1

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [a `namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content) instead of an interface, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy66Kw)?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in a reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks would appreciate it, I think maybe that could work for me. I thought it was deprecated or something? But maybe it's just what I need.

Comment: Namespaces aren't deprecated (see [ms/TS#30994](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994)) but the recommendation is generally that new code use `module`s instead of `namespace`s.  The problem for me is that `module`s require multiple files, and I can't demonstrate that in the TS playground, and most multi-file web IDEs seem to be "iffy" with TS.  I can *try* to look into the equivalent `module` representation, assuming you're okay with multi-file (and I'm hoping you are, otherwise you'd just write `Item` in one block instead of using declaration merging)

Comment: @jcalz I'm fine with multifile but think would prefer namespaces atm since it's not deprecated. I do want to use it in the same file along with multifile.

Comment: All right then I won't go crazy trying to research modules to see if there's a way to get the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination here would be to use [`namespace`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#handbook-content) instead of an interface to hold these functions.  It could look like this:

```
namespace Item {
  export const buy = function () {
    Item.render()
    return "bought"
  }
}

namespace Item {
  export const sell = function () {
    Item.render()
    return "sold"
  }
}

namespace Item {
  export const render = function () {
    return 1
  }
}
```

Then you'd be able to access them the same way, as methods on the singleton `Item` value:

```
// elsewhere
console.log(Item.sell()); // "sold"
```

---

Note that `namespace` is a TypeScript specific feature, and nowadays new code is generally encouraged to use [`module`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) instead where possible.  I don't really know if there's a good way to get this sort of behavior with modules, because the part we're using, merging different things into a common JS value, is not really how modules works.  Maybe declaration merging and importing would give this to you, but I don't know.

Anyway, as long as you're okay with a TS-specific feature, then `namespace` would be an idiomatic way to represent this sort of gradual building of a singleton.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&pretty=true&ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBJALhMSDeAoJSEAHjAPYBOaS8pwUVARgK4CeSAvEgGZPDxoBLWkgAUAShz4CqDGAB05CMAAmEcuKkFFaJuWBIARA1JMA5gAs0BqQF9cd3KEiwEydJkkFiZStVr0kKAgAG2CObl5+IX1xT2l3eUUVNQ1pJG1dfQMoUmDlawI7BydoOEQZDzwvEgoqGjoqJNVycJ4+QWFYqukMvSQARlt7XBGAelHCYKCAd3M1CFx6nOCIOWDSUxEEuSDQ8TEAbiRxw2X8oA)

Comment: Thank you this totally works though the output looks kinda awful but I guess I'll just ignore that haha. I also just discovered @ts-expect-error which lets me use interface without setting the property to optional. Do you think that might be better for me.

Comment: I would stay away from those directives since they just suppress errors instead of telling the compiler what you mean.  Probably if you're doing that then you should just use a type assertion when you create `const Item = {}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZXXPw), since that's the closest to what you mean... `Item` will be a valid `Item` by the time you're done, even though the initializer is not.

Comment: Oh thankyou, TIL difference between assertion and annotation.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION 1:**

Since you have not defined any method inside `Item`

```
interface Item {}
```

So you can check whether `render` method exist or not on `Item` as:

```
Item.buy = function () {
  if(Item.render) Item.render();  // CHANGE
  return "bought";
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Best solution would be to add type of `render` on `interface` `Item` as:

```
interface Item {
    render: () => void;
}
```

and then you can use it as:

```
Item.buy = function () {
  Item.render();
  return "bought";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to find an alternative to these for DX reasons.