# nested namespace typescript Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4OwQwWwUwZwA4QMY2AJ3gewK7tcAN4BQooMAHglugC7jTxIECWtMURpZ5VN9kWIhRoAFrjgswAcy48elanWDIsYOAMbAAvMABEACQlTpe7vIC+50FbJXiDsqvX0ARjgCeO4ADMcYZFoWNWAAChYAEwAuYA10EwBKOXkVNQ1gNg5BNF1MOFx8GAA6TKgAbUiAXSLs6wsgA

This errors with:

```
namespace resource {
  export namespace item {
    export namespace housing {
      export const name = "Housing"
    }
    export namespace healthcare {
      export const name = "Healthcare"
    }
    export namespace food {
      export const name = "Food"
    }
  }
}


const buy = function (id: string) {
    const itemname = resource.item[id].name
}
```

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof item'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof item'.

I'm trying to access fields of item with the bracket notation. How can I do that? I saw other questions with this error message but they all refer to interfaces instead of namespaces.

Comment: Why are you using namespaces?

Comment: @caTS was recommended from my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070283/typescript-resolving-not-actually-optional-optional-property

Comment: `item` should not be a namespace then? It should just be an object?

Comment: @caTS Maybe like this? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAnaB7ArixSDeAUEkhAB4zooAuS86wUNAllRGEgLz5HFIAWWKE2ABzAFzdevUJAkAiABKDhIuT2IBfHlq0ECdBjQBGmAJ6ckAM0zB4VJvSQAKJgBMJjFCoCUk3gcYkFjYZZC40KCwcCAA6YLAAbTcAXRjQgg0gA